# Set current route programmatically; setCurrentRoute is missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I just upgraded to Laravel 4.1 and can no longer use a function I was using in the past. I wrote a function to redirect an incoming request to another route, get the result, and replace the current route with the original incoming route. I used this on my frontend controllers to consume my own API which is defined in the same application.

Here is the function:

```
public static function redirectRequest($newRoute, $verb, $args = null)
{
    // store the original request data and route
    $originalInput = Request::input();
    $originalRoute = Route::current();

    $request = $args === null ? Request::create($newRoute, $verb) : Request::create($newRoute, $verb, $args);

    // replace the request input for the new route...
    Request::replace($request->input());

    try
    {
        $response = Route::dispatch($request);

        return $response;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        throw $e;
    }
    finally
    {
        // replace the request input and route back to the original state
        Request::replace($originalInput);
        Route::setCurrentRoute($originalRoute);
    }
}
```

And I would use it like:

```
Helpers::redirectRequest('/api/v1/someroute', 'GET');
```

The problem is that, when I try to return things to the way they were before the redirect, I can't. `setCurrentRoute` has been removed from 4.1 and I can't figure out how to reset the current route.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have done in the past is used the actual routes.php to handle that. If you register a "catchall" route as:

```
Route::get('api/v1', 'ApiController@route');
```

As long as this is after all other routes (Laravel uses the first matching route) you can then handle that within your ApiController as

```
public function route($uri) {
    // Handle your API route using the $uri variable
}
```

This may not be the solution that you are looking for, but I have found it very convenient.